# Speeding up SQL transfer over a network

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have two SQL Server environments, data warehouse which collects data and a datamart which people access for a subset of the data, each with their own SQL Server 2016 databases. I run a script which pulls out data, transforms it and transfer it from the data warehouse to the datamart using Linked Servers. The entire process takes around 60+ hours to run. I want to avoid at all costs at having the data warehouse data in the datamart.

I experimented to see why the whole process was taking so long. I did a backup of the data warehouse, restored it onto the datamart and ran the import script and the entire process took around 3 hours to run. The script itself to 1.5 hours, telling me of the 60+ hours its the linked server transfer of data between the two servers that is the slowest part. I've pretty much ruled out network speed or issues between the two servers; this is all SQL. I'm trying to avoid having to write an application to do all of this in .NET if I can keep it in SQL Server.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve performance time between SQL Server transfers?

Comment: Rather than linked servers, use an ETL process using SSIS or other custom ETL.

Comment: @DanGuzman If a direct link was very slow I dont think SSIS will be faster

Comment: @asmgx, linked servers add an additional OLEDB remote query layer and associated [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) overhead, which is why they are not commonly used for ETL processes. SSIS is specifically designed for DW loads, leveraging high-performance transformations and bulk inserts.

Comment: @DanGuzman wouldn't you have 2 OLEDB layers in SSIS one to extract from the source and one to load in the destination?

Answer (score 0):

The slowliness could be from the destination database 
try disable triggers, indexes, locks, etc.

look at this link may help more

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e04a8e21-54a9-46a4-8eb2-67da291dc7e1/slow-data-transfer-through-linked-server?forum=transactsql